# Crystal report in asp.net

Tags: crystal-reports

Im new to work with Crystal Report in asp.net....I ve to import datatables to show report to client..So give me some links or solution to know about it.
thanks in advance

Comment: you poor soul (crystal reports terror)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of links available on [Google](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&source=hp&q=asp.net+crystal+reports&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=asp.net+crystal+reports&fp=53b27f7a7a96cd50).  The Code Project also has some good articles including [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CrystalWin.aspx).